# Keep getting error for dismissing a popup

Tags: python, kivy

Still learning to use Kivy and now facing a problem of creating a close button for the popup. Intended to implement in kv file, and from the doc, I know the script is on_release = root.dismiss(). But don't know why keep saying "AttributeError: 'PricePopup' object has no attribute 'dismiss' "

Python file

```
class AmazonFront(Widget):
    asin = ObjectProperty(None)
    country = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit_button(self):
        item = Item(self.asin)
        item.add_country(self.country)
        item_info(item)

    def popup_price(self):
        show_pricePopup(self.asin.text)

class PricePopup(FloatLayout):
    name = StringProperty()
    pass

def show_pricePopup(ASIN):
    show = PricePopup()
    store = JsonStore('Price.json')
    show.name = str(store.get(ASIN)['name'])
    popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    popupWindow.open()


class AmazonApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AmazonFront()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AmazonApp().run()
```

kv file

```
<AmazonFront>

    asin: Asin
    country: cn

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width-200, root.height-200
        pos: 100,100

        GridLayout:
            cols : 2
            Label:
                text: "ASIN"
            TextInput:
                id: Asin
                multinline : False

            Label:
                text: "Amazon Country"
            TextInput:
                id: cn
                multinline :False

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.submit_button()
            on_press: root.popup_price()


<PricePopup>

    Label:
        text: "Name: {}".format(root.name)
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}

    Button:
        text: "Close"
        on_press:  root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `PricePopup` class does not have a `dismiss()` method. You can either create such a method that calls the `dismiss()` method of the `popupWindow` (you will need to save a reference to `popupWindow`) or your `kv` can call the `dismiss()` method on the saved `popupWindow` reference.

Or you can just include the `dismiss` `Button` in the `popupWindow` like this:

```
def show_pricePopup(ASIN):
    show = PricePopup()
    store = JsonStore('Price.json')
    show.name = str(store.get(ASIN)['name'])

    # create content for the Popup
    bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    label = Label(text=show.name)
    bl.add_widget(label)

    # create the Popup
    popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window", content=bl, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    # add dimiss Button to the Popup content
    bl.add_widget(Button(text='dismiss', on_release=popupWindow.dismiss))

    popupWindow.open()
```

Note that the `PricePopup` class is not actually neeeded.

Comment: thanks @john-anderson, now I managed to add a button and dismiss in python script with 

btn = Button(text='Close', on_release=popupWindow.dismiss) 
show.add_widget(btn)

but how to do the same in kv file?